# Traveling constantly towards West. That is clockwise

Tags: orbit

If I travel against against the Earth's rotation. Say once around the world. I will always see sunrise and never a sunset
Is that accurate?

Comment: How fast are you traveling, and at what latitude?

Comment: But trivially, in most places on Earth, if a human walks west continuously, that human will experience a sunset in less than 25 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you travel west so quickly that you go around the world in one day (24 hours) then the sun will remain almost fixed in the sky. You will see neither a sunrise nor a sunset.  At a latitude of 45 degrees north, you will need to travel at 1180 km/h (faster than a commercial jet, nearly Mach 1)

If you travel less quickly, then the sun will move from East to West, but rather more slowly. You may see multiple sunrises and sunsets, depending on your speed.

If you travel faster, the sun will move from West to East in the sky.  Again, you may see multiple sunrises and sunsets, but the sun would rise in the West.

Comment: If you're far enough north at the right time of year, you can do this while standing still!